# Order by multi-column that include sort by field collection size spring jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I don't think it is duplicate of [Order by count using Spring Data JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136469/order-by-count-using-spring-data-jparepository).

Let me explain my problem:-

I have a domain object called Account that consists of name, status, list of group objects, list of membership objects.

for example:-

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    private String name;
    private String status;

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "account",orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Group> groups;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Membership> memberships;


    // getters and setters..

}


@Eintity
public class Group{
    // fields and getters setters..
}


@Eintity
public class Membership{
    // fields and getters setters..
}
```

I am using spring data JPA repository to find all accounts and passing pageable and querydsl predicate arguments(for instance `Page<Account> allAccountsPage = accountRepository.findAll(querydslPredicate, pageable);`). If I just want to sort accounts by name and/or status it worked great using pageable but if I want to sort by groups size and/or memberships size JPA repository is not working for me.

I found one possible solution(i.e. [Order by count using Spring Data JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136469/order-by-count-using-spring-data-jparepository)) but that is good for just single column sorting but I need to implement multi-column sorting that may include name, status, groups(by size), memberships(by size) and also in any order.

**Is there any possible and graceful way to do that?**

**EDIT:-**

Found a way using hibernate's @Formula annotation.

Here is a way:-

```
@Entity
    public class Account {
        private String name;
        private String status;

        @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "account",orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<Group> groups;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<Membership> memberships;


    @Formula("(select count(*) from groups where groups.account_id=id)")
    private long groupSize;


    @Formula("(select count(*) from membership where membership.account_id=id)")
    private long membershipSize;

        // getters and setters..

    }
```

Now simply use hibernate criteria to find all accounts and instead of sort by group and/or membership now you can sort it by groupSize and membershipSize.

But that's not a good way to do that because @formula creates a subquery that makes your query slow. Also, for every * select query on Account hibernate hit subquery to get groupSize and membershipSize that makes every query very slow.

So above solution is not a graceful way to solve my problem. **Can anybody suggest better solution than that?**