# Spring data jpa sort by nested object collection size

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using a spring boot application and there exists the following 2 entities.

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person extends BaseEntity {
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusType status;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "PERSON_ADDRESS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Info> addresses;
}
```

**Address.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address extends BaseEntity {
    @NotNull
    private String address;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "addresses")
    private Collection<Person> persons;
}
```

I am using a `JpaRepository` as follows.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

And I use the following statement to implement the pagination and sorting.

```
Page<Person> allPersons = personRepository.findAll(pageable);
```

where `pageable` is an instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable`.

I am able to sort using the other columns in `Person`. But I want to sort based on the addresses collection, based on the number of `Address` record for each `Person` entity.

In short, I wanted to sort the Persons **based on the collection size of Collection**. The sorting order (ASC or DESC) comes from the front end.

Any idea how the `Pageable` object should look like to implement this? Also without returning any duplicate `Person` record if more than one `Address` exist for a `Person`.

Comment: Spring Data JPa has a lot of very effective features but it's not omnipotent. You have to create a unique query... or a Specification because you can use it together with Pageable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution according to [Order by count using Spring Data JpaRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136469/order-by-count-using-spring-data-jparepository).

In my experiment, I tried to define Repository as follows, but there is problem with that; as we are defining the query on `PersonRepository` for sorting based on addressCount spring data looks into Person.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query(
        value = "select p from Person p join p.addresses ad group by p",
        countQuery = "select count(p) from Person p"
    )
    Page <Person> findAllWithAddressCount(Pageable pageable);
}
```

So as a workaround I tried to shift the sorting logic into query definition itself and I end up with 2 versions for ASC and DESC mode:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository <Person, Long> {

    @Query(
        value = "select p from Person p join p.addresses ad group by p Order By addressCount asc",
        countQuery = "select count(p) from Person p"
    )
    Page<Person> findAllOrderByAddressCountAsc(Pageable pageable);

    @Query(
        value = "select p from Person p join p.addresses ad group by p Order By addressCount desc",
        countQuery = "select count(p) from Person p"
    )
    Page<Person> findAllOrderByAddressCountDesc(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: And what will be the Pageable object sort field be like?

Comment: Also if there are only 6 persons with 3 of them having 2 addresses and the remaining persons one address each, then if we use this countQuery, I will get 9 person records right? With 3 of them duplicate

Comment: @PhilipJohni i experimented it and changed my proposed solution,please check

Comment: Hmm I had seen this solution in another stackoverflow post and wanted to know if there was any alternative way. Maybe you can add also the link to the original answer as a reference to your answer.

Comment: @PhilipJohn reference given

Comment: What is `addressCount` ?