# Sort On Child List total count using JpaRepository Spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, sorting, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have a requirement of paging and sorting an entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY", catalog = "")
public class CategoryEntity {
 private CategoryEntity categoryByParentCategoryId;
 private Set<CategoryEntity> categoriesByCategoryId;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID")
public CategoryEntity getCategoryByParentCategoryId() {
    return categoryByParentCategoryId;
}

public void setCategoryByParentCategoryId(CategoryEntity categoryByParentCategoryId) {
    this.categoryByParentCategoryId = categoryByParentCategoryId;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryByParentCategoryId", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
public Set<CategoryEntity> getCategoriesByCategoryId() {
    return categoriesByCategoryId;
}

public void setCategoriesByCategoryId(Set<CategoryEntity> categoriesByCategoryId) {
    this.categoriesByCategoryId = categoriesByCategoryId;
}
```

From [this link](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/create-paging-sorting-result-spring-jpa-postgresql-spring-boot) and other stack overflow answers, I found out that I can use sorting and paging using `Paging Request` like

```
Pageable size = new PageRequest(page, paginationDTO.getSize(),Sort.Direction.ASC, "id");
```

My problem is I have a `self join` parent and child relationship as shown above in the model and I need to sort the parent based on the count of child as shown below.

[image: Data table for Category Entity]

Here the `Number of SubCategories` is the size of `categoriesByCategoryId`. What do I need to pass in the `PageRequest` in the place of `id` to sort on basis of size of list of child.

**PS. The model has more fields but for the question to be short I posted only the relevant fields**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23160019/2819935) I was able to achieve the requirement by using a custom query, the method in JPARepository looked like

```
@Query(
        value = "select c from CategoryEntity c " +
                " WHERE LOWER(c.categoryNameEn) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%',?2, '%')) AND activeInd = ?1 " +
                "AND c.categoryByParentCategoryId is null" +
                " Order By c.categoriesByCategoryId.size desc",
        countQuery = "select count(c) from CategoryEntity c " +
                " WHERE LOWER(c.categoryNameEn) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%',?2, '%')) AND activeInd = ?1" +
                " AND c.categoryByParentCategoryId is null"
)
Page<CategoryEntity> findAllActiveCategoriesByCategoriesByCategoryIdCountDesc(String activeInd, String categoryNameEn, Pageable pageable);
```

The Count query is needed for pagination details.