# Spring boot JPA - Order by Entity collection

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am try to sort the data by collection size for a certain period.

I have

**Title Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Title {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length=120, nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "title", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<TitleVisitor> visitors = new HashSet<>();

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
```

**TitleVisitor Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TitleVisitor implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TitleVisitorId id = new TitleVisitorId();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("titleId")
    private Title title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("visitorId")
    private Visitor visitor;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
```

**Title repository**

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long> {
    @Override
    Optional<Movie> findById(Long aLong);

    @Query(
            value = "SELECT m FROM Movie m LEFT JOIN TitleVisitor tv ON m.id = tv.id.titleId WHERE tv.createdAt >= DATEADD(day,-7, NOW()) GROUP BY tv.id.titleId",
            countQuery = "select count(tv.id.titleId) from TitleVisitor tv"
    )
    Page<Movie> findAllWithTitleVisitorCountOrderByCountDesc(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**Title service**

```
    public Page<Title> findPaginated(int page, int size) {
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "visitors"));

        return this.titleRepository.findAll(paging);
    }
```

I need select paginated data (Title Entity) and sort all title entities by count of title visits in the last day/week/month/overall

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by *I need paginated data sorted by count( title visits in the last day/week/month/overall (createdAt attribute in TitleVisit entity) )*. you want to do it application level or you are suggesting with a query?

Comment: A am using JPA Repository for select data.

I need select paginated data (Title Entity)  and sort all title entities by count of title visits in the last day/week/month/overall

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I added more details. I'm a beginner in spring boot and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Do you know how to do it in SQL?   If you know that then it will much easier for you to write it in JPQL. Can you show us ?

Comment: I know SQL.....

Comment: Can you show us how you can do it SQL? Show us some effort. SO is not code service. Though this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136469/order-by-count-using-spring-data-jparepository/23160019#23160019

Comment: `SELECT *, count(title_visitor.visitor_id) as visitors FROM title LEFT JOIN title_visitor ON title.id = title_visitor.title_id WHERE title_visitor.created_at >= DATEADD(day,-7, NOW()) GROUP BY title.id ORDER BY count(title_visitor.visitor_id) DESC`

Comment: I don't know how to use this command in JPA repository.

Comment: You can read about JPA repository here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories and how to write custom query in JPQL and  use `@Query` look here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query. Sol: Use `@Query` to run native query that you have already for an easier way.

Comment: I updated the repository class in the question. 
Lists the results but does not sort them.

Comment: I appreciate your effort to solve own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` in JPQL rather than use sort param in `pageable` since you use custom order.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM Title t LEFT JOIN t.visitors tv "
         + "WHERE tv.createdAt >= :dateTime GROUP BY t ORDER BY COUNT(tv.visitor.id) DESC",
            countQuery = "select count(t.id) from Title t")
    Page<Title> findByTitleVisitorCountCount(LocalDateTime dateTime, Pageable pageable);
```

Here, calculate `dateTime` for last day/week/month/overall